# How do I create custom text macros in Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode, ios4

I updated to Xcode 4 today and my custom text macros are no longer working. I cannot find any information on how to use custom macros with Xcode 4. Is this still possible? Please let me know if anyone has come up with a solution.

This is the directory where I currently have my 'ObjectiveC.xctxtmacro' file.
~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Specifications

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The format of how Text Macros are defined, and where they live has changed - Text Macros have morphed into Code Snippets.

What you can do is make a new code snippet (with anything, just drag text into the Code Snippet window), then go looking for the current format of a Snippet (Macro), and migrate your current macros into there.

The directory where they go is:

```
~/Library/Developer/XCode/UserData/CodeSnippets
```

In there you'll see files with names like:

```
E4B300B5-E0EA-4E46-9963-6E9B2111E578.codesnippet
```

The great thing is, you don't have to use UUID names - I was able to copy one of those into a file called "MyTest.codesnippet" and XCode still reads it.

So you'd have one file per existing macro (as there are usually a number of macros in the older .xctxtmacro files), you can use the actual macro text as-is as the parameter syntax has not changed (although all of the meta-data around a macro has changed substantially).  You will have to convert the "<" / ">" parts of any parameters defined to XML-safe syntax `&lt;` / `&gt;` as the files are XML plists now.  As an example, the contents of a simple macro that produces `NSLog(@"Hello Nurse: %@",`**Thing**`);` when "nurse" is typed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>IDECodeSnippetCompletionPrefix</key>
    <string>nurse</string>
    <key>IDECodeSnippetCompletionScopes</key>
    <array>
        <string>All</string>
    </array>
    <key>IDECodeSnippetContents</key>
    <string>NSLog(@"Hello Nurse %@", &lt;#Thing#&gt;);
</string>
    <key>IDECodeSnippetIdentifier</key>
    <string>E4B300B5-E0EA-4E46-9963-6E9B2111E579</string>
    <key>IDECodeSnippetLanguage</key>
    <string>Xcode.SourceCodeLanguage.Objective-C</string>
    <key>IDECodeSnippetTitle</key>
    <string>TestNurse</string>
    <key>IDECodeSnippetUserSnippet</key>
    <true/>
    <key>IDECodeSnippetVersion</key>
    <integer>2</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Note that one aspect of Code Snippets that is missing from Text Macros, is that you used to be able to define parameters where selected text would go when you activated a Text Macro (by adding `!` after the `#` as in `<#!ReplaceParam!#>` ) - in the Code Snippet system, there does not appear to be a way to apply a Code Snippet to selected text, you can only drag it out as new.  The parameters still work as normal parameters though.

Comment: Thank you so much for the in-depth answer. I relied on the custom text macros a lot and this was killing me. And it is so weird how you knew that I always include 'Hello Nurse' in my log statements. ;)

Comment: In a way the new system is a little better.  More people can create Code Snippets now I think since they don't have to create a directory and file somewhere.  Also the completion works better, you used to have to type the completion and manually force recognition with Ctrl-. , but now you just type a bit of the completion and hit return and off it goes.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you meant, but you can use <#paramName#> to define a parameter.

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you. And for anyone viewing in the future, you can write your `IDECodeSnippetContents` in XCode and just copy it all right into the `.codesnippet` file, including any parameters (They will copy directly as `<#(NSData *)#>`, as an example.