# Xcode 4 NSLog Macro link in Xcode 3 

Tags: xcode, xcode4

In Xcode < version 4, there was a macro to quickly write `NSLog`statements. I could type (I think, using my motor memory):

```
log control+.
```

And the code complete/macro would do:

```
 NSLog(|);
```

`|` being the cursor.

Is there anything similar to accomplish this in Xcode 4?

Thanks
Ross

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really miss this macro too. Thanks to [Kendall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6330/kendall-helmstetter-gelner)'s [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303374/how-do-i-create-custom-text-macros-in-xcode-4), I was able to recreate it.

Go to this folder or create one if doesn't exist:

`~/Library/Developer/XCode/UserData/CodeSnippets`

Then create a file called NSLog.codesnippet and paste in the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>IDECodeSnippetCompletionPrefix</key>
    <string>log</string>
    <key>IDECodeSnippetCompletionScopes</key>
    <array>
        <string>All</string>
    </array>
    <key>IDECodeSnippetContents</key>
    <string>NSLog(@"&lt;#Comment#&gt;");
</string>
    <key>IDECodeSnippetIdentifier</key>
    <string>nslog1</string>
    <key>IDECodeSnippetLanguage</key>
    <string>Xcode.SourceCodeLanguage.Objective-C</string>
    <key>IDECodeSnippetTitle</key>
    <string>NSLogComment</string>
    <key>IDECodeSnippetUserSnippet</key>
    <true/>
    <key>IDECodeSnippetVersion</key>
    <integer>2</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Restart Xcode and type l into a file in your project. If autocomplete isn't showing, hit escape and then choose the "log - NSLog comment" option and then hit tab.

After you've used it once, you'll probably only need to use l+tab for the autocomplete.

You can create as many as you like. Just make sure the filename, the IDECodeSnippetIdentifier and the IDECodeSnippetCompletionPrefix are all unique.

More examples are available on [GitHub](https://github.com/noodles/CodeSnippets).

Comment: prefect, even better than the original macro.

Answer (score 0):

Type `NSL` and press escape, the autocomplete will handle the rest.

Comment: This isn't the same, I don't think.  I think log control+ would even insert NSLog(@""); rather than just complete 'NSLog'.