# Objective-C: Trigger method with computer keyboard stroke

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, keystroke

Sorry if the questions is asked/answered already, or if my title is poorly worded.

I am currently writing an iPhone app, and have considered a useful tool for debugging. I would like to write a method that just prints variables and other info that I want. That part is simple and all, but I want this to be called by keystroke.

For now I have been just adding NSLog()'s to viewDidLoad or to other button methods to check if my variables are being set properly, but it's becoming tedious and the code is long so I tend to forget about some and spend a lot of time looking for them haha.

I just want one method that I can go to to write my NSLog()'s, and have that method call whenever I hit 'space' or something of that sort.

Can this be done?
Thanks!
-SF

Comment: Why not just use breakpoints and the debugger? You can see variable on the break points and use the console to get more info

Comment: Have a look here for macros (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303374/how-do-i-create-custom-text-macros-in-xcode-4 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817839/xcode-4-nslog-macro-link-in-xcode-3)

Comment: On an iPhone, the soft keyboard isn't always available. You might rely on an external keyboard — or, presumably, you're referring to the Simulator. The thing is, you would have no idea where you are in code when hitting a key on the keyboard. All in all, this seems a terrible idea.

Comment: -AlexReynolds YEs I have been using debugger from time to time, but I would like to see things on the fly while testing the app in real time.
-Magla Sorry, I must not have worded the question correctly. I do not want the keystroke to manipulate code. I want to call a method that is in the code, while running the simulator.
-magma "seems a terrible idea" just makes me think you are a dick. This is a good idea, if not for you or for other doesn't matter. I am looking for a way to check up on variables and such on the fly while in the simulator. Which is very obviously useful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty hard to do, you need to have a hidden text field that you keep in focus, hide the software keyboard for it, then listen on its delegate methods for changing text.

An alternative would trigger the code inside `applicationWillResignActive:` which gets called on application hiding, notification center showing, or double home press.

Comment: Thank you. Seems like more trouble than it is worth. I'll just stick to debugging and random NSLog()'s haha.